# Spring ldap unlocking an account

Tags: active-directory, ldap, spring-ldap

I am trying to unlock user account using spring ldap and getting the error message 
`""Malformed 'LockoutTime' attribute value" exception`.

My code looks like below

```
public boolean unlockAccount(Name dn) {
        ModificationItem item = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("lockoutTime", 0));
        ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(dn, new ModificationItem[] {item});
        return true;
}
```

I am using Windows server 2016 and Spring ldap 2.3.2.

Is 'lockoutTime' the correct attribute to unlock an account ?
Is there anything else I am missing ?

Comment: Every example I can find says that `lockoutTime` is the correct attribute, and it needs to be set to 0 to unlock. But I haven't used Java with AD, so I can't be much more help.

Answer (score 2):

In LDAP if you type the wrong password for more than 5 times, the account gets locked. If you want to unlock the user you have to delete an operational attribute name as pwdAccountLockedTime.

```
    public String unlockUser(Users pvo) {
    System.out.println("this is pvo" + pvo);

    Name dn = buildDn(pvo);
    DirContextOperations context = ldapTemplate.lookupContext(dn);
    ModificationItem[] modificationItems;
    modificationItems = new ModificationItem[1];

    modificationItems[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE,
            new BasicAttribute("pwdAccountLockedTime"));

    ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(dn, modificationItems);

    return "Account Unlocked";
}
```

build Dn for your LDAP and use the above code then the user gets unlocked.

Comment: I have a requirement that user account will be locked if user tries with multiple incorrect password and alternatively admin can also lock the account, for incorrect pwd attempts I can use the attribute "pwdAccountLockedTime" but is there any recommendation for the admin lock?

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] attrIDs = new String[] { "lockoutTime", "sAMAccountName", 
"distinguishedName","pwdLastSet", "accountExpires", "userAccountControl", 
"IsAccountLocked" };

ctls.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);
ctls.setSearchScope(2); 

String filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=" + 
samaccountname+ "))";

NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search(adManagedOU, filter,ctls);

while (answer.hasMore()) {

    SearchResult rs = answer.next();

    Attributes attrs = rs.getAttributes();

    distinguishedName = rs.getNameInNamespace();

 String[] lockouttime = null;
```

String lockOutValue=attrs.get("lockoutTime");

if (lockOutValue != null)

{

```
lockouttime = attrs.get("lockoutTime").toString().split(":");

if (Long.valueOf(lockouttime[1].trim()) > 0) {

ModificationItem[] mods1 = new ModificationItem[] {
```

new ModificationItem(2, new BasicAttribute("lockoutTime", "0") )
};

((DirContext) ctls).modifyAttributes(distinguishedName, mods1);

}
else
{

LOGGER.info(username + " Account Not Locked");

}

Answer (score 0):

The only values that may be set on [lockouttime](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Lockouttime) is to set the value to "0" which will effectively un-lock the account.

To learn more on [Microsoft Active Directory Lockouts](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20Account%20Lockout).

Answer (score 0):

Setting the value to a **String** instead of an int makes this work, at least with AWS Simple AD.

```
 ModificationItem item = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("lockoutTime", "0"));
    ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(dn, new ModificationItem[] {item});
```